# Is there a way to keep undesirialized json fields after desrialization and reserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, microservices, decoupling

We are implementing a microservices based system. In order to keep loose coupling as possible, the system is event driven, meanning based on kafka pubsub mechanism. Now, some of the microservices are written in java spring so the messages are deserialized into objects. This, ofcourse causing the java based microservices to be titghly coupled to changes on the messages schema. 
We tried to find solutions to this seems-to-be-basic problem, including avro schema but coudlnt find a way of suporting schema changes without recompiling all pojos. We will be glad to know about any library facing this problem or any solution you found.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Recent i Use deserialized / serialize json working in my java code.

you can find my code from below link .but it is designed according to my json objects. 
i can help you to design this according to your requirements.

https://github.com/MuhammadFaisal1521/Java-Application-Inventory-Management-System-with-Oracle-Database/tree/master/src/Shopify